# Django, Ajax and GET requests

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

There are plenty of similar questions here but I can't solve that problem I have. Situation is simple in theory - I send json to Django view, I get a json response. I did it with python, with Django, with REST framework. But with Ajax I can't do it, there's something with URLconf and ajax's relative url kind of stuff and I can't figure out what's wrong and how to make it work. I mean with some URL confs I can send a request with my chrome plugin and I have a response I need, but ajax is getting 404 with that confs. If I change it Django starts to return my html page instead of json response. What am I missing here?
My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/apply_city/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'city': obj.textContent
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var str = '';
            data.districts.forEach(function (district) {
                str += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="applyDistrict(this)">' + district + '</a>';
            });
            window.alert(str);
            document.getElementById("district_dropdown").innerHTML = str;
        },
    });
```

urls that works with requests from everything but not ajax:

```
    re_path('^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path('^index/ajax/apply_city/', views.apply_city, name='apply_city'),
```

Logs show `Not Found: /index/...` when ajax makes request and `GET /index/... 404`. I've seen that for ajax I shouldn't close url with `$` sign. If I do `^index/` I get HTML page as a response (but with HTTP200). Maybe that's some Django issue or I don't understand how to do it properly. If anyone knows how to fix it please help.

Comment: seems like the url `ajax/apply_city/` isn't a *absolute URL*. You may need to provide the absolute url as, `/index/ajax/apply_city/`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I tried that and result is the same 404

Comment: can you check the url which is actually using by the ajax request by inspecting the Netwotk section of browser?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu my god I'm stupid as hell! I used bootstrap's version of jQuery that has not ajax function. Thanks for telling me where to look for the errors!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you put the wrong URL. You can try changing the URL within ajax just like below:

```
url: "{% url 'apple_city' %}",
```

Comment: Thanks but I figured out that it was all my fault and I used wrong version of jQuery.